# Outgoing docker packets not respecting routing rules

Tags: iptables, docker, routing, iproute, wireguard

I have a private docker host (A) connected via a Wireguard tunnel to a public "router" in a cloud environment (B).

Wireguard:

```
(Docker Container)
eth0 172.17.0.2
|
docker0 172.17.0.1
(A) eth0 192.168.1.2 --- Internet (can't accept conns)
wg0 10.0.16.6
|
wg0 10.0.16.5
(B) 
eth0 public IP Q
|
USER
```

The idea is to have traffic first go to B on it's public IP and then forward the request to B and forward the responses back.

I have followed [this guide](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2022/09/wireguard-port-forward-from-internet/), specifically the Policy Routing section.

The wireguard configuration on A is as follows:

```
[Interface]
Address = 10.0.16.6/30
Table = 123

PreUp = ip rule add from 10.0.16.6 table 123 priority 456
PostDown = ip rule del from 10.0.16.6 table 123 priority 456

[Peer]
AllowedIPs = 0.0.0.0/0
Endpoint = Q:51820
PersistentKeepalive = 30
```

The packet with source 10.0.16.6 and destination of the original sender should be routed over the wg0 interface because of this rule:

```
0:  from all lookup local
456:    from 10.0.16.6 lookup 123 ### This one
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  from all lookup default
```

So on A, a packet from B enters from the wireguard interface (with destination address 10.0.16.6) and gets routed to the docker http server correctly.

Then as the response packet comes back out from the docker container to A, it has the container's source address. This means that the routing rule above doesn't get respected like it would if the http server was running on the host A.

The packet ends up being NATed after the routing and then sent off on A eth0 instead of A wg0.

I would like the packets to get re-routed after the NAT stage.

Any regular traffic leaving the docker container should not go over the wg0 interface, only traffic originating from the wg0 interface as the referenced guide suggests.

If any further information is required, I am happy to provide e.g. `iptables -L` etc

Comment: What is generating the problematic traffic? Are you certain it has the expected source address? If it's coming from a container, what is the address of that container? Note that packets coming from a container will not have the source address of your host during the routing decision.

Comment: Could be anything but for testing I've just been using an http server. The source address is that of the wireguard interface but it's leaving via the default route.
That is the problem I think, I need to figure out a way to get the routing to happen once the packets have the host address...

Comment: Your question title is "Outgoing docker packets", which suggests you're running e.g. the http server in a container. If that's the case, you would need to match the container address in your routing rule. If you believe that's not the case, updating the question to include sufficient information for us to reproduce the problem would be helpful in formulating a complete answer.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I've re-written the question to hopefully be more clear.
I can't match the container's address because not all traffic from the container should go over the wg0 interface. Only that which originated from wg0.

Comment: Then you need to use the *destination* address in your policy rule, rather than the *source* address (because you want to route traffic going *to* the wireguard network).

Comment: The destination address isn't the wireguard ip, it's the original sender IP on the internet. The public router doesn't perform SNAT when forwarding packets over wireguard.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted *all* the traffic from the Docker container to go out the Docker host's WireGuard connection, you could use the policy routing technique you've outlined -- but using the *Docker container's* IP address in the policy routing rule:

```
ip rule add from 172.17.0.2 table 123 priority 456
```

The *Docker host's* IP address won't work for this rule to route traffic forwarded from the container, however, because SNAT is applied *after* the host has already made its routing decision.

So if you need *only return traffic* that originated through the WireGuard connection to be routed back out the WireGuard connection, you'll need to use connection marking on the Docker host. The core of this technique is three steps:

1. Set a custom connection mark on new connections incoming through the WireGuard interface:

   ```
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i wg0 -m state --state NEW -j CONNMARK --set-mark 1
   ```
2. On outgoing connections, copy the connection mark to the packet mark:

   ```
    iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING ! -i wg0 -m connmark --mark 1 -j MARK --set-mark 1
   ```
3. Use the packet mark in your policy routing rules to route packets back out the WireGuard interface:

   ```
    ip rule add fwmark 1 table 123 priority 456
   ```

See the "Connmark on the Intermediate Server" section of the companion article to the guide you linked for more notes and caveats: [WireGuard Port Forwarding From the Internet to Other Networks](https://www.procustodibus.com/blog/2023/11/wireguard-port-forward-from-internet-multi-hop/).